# calculate derivative for standard inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

$L\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ $L_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some inner product, $DL$ be the derivative of $L$. Its a Linear map so I know derivative will be itself only.
 I want to calculate explicitly the derivative for standard inner product, could any one help me?
$y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$
Then $L_y(x)=x_1y_1+\dots+x_ny_n$ using standard inner product.
Now what I have to do?

In particular $DL(u)=DL(v)\quad \forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The function $L_y: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable if there exists a linear transformation $\lambda: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that,

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|L_y(x+h) - L_y(x) - \lambda(h)|}{|h|} = 0.$$

In this case we know it's differentiable so $DL_y = \lambda$.

I won't work it out because if you substitute for $L_y$ above and expand the inner products you'll immediately see what $\lambda(h)$ must be for the limit to be $0.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: So do you want to say derivative of the operator is a 0 operator?

Comment: No definitely not. The derivative is $\lambda$. In a first course in calculus we define the derivative at $a$ to be

$$f^\prime(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$

But we could write this as,

$$0 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a) - f^\prime(a)\cdot h}{h}$$

Understand now that I'm not saying that the derivative is $0$?

Comment: @Taxi Driver Has this helped?